# How to make a conditional dropdown base on cell values using VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, dropdown

I am trying to make a dropdown in Excel 2016, but as don't use it often, I don't now how to do it.

The data looks like this :

[image: Excel data screenshot]

I am trying to create a dropdown which will contains the values of "Title 1", "Title2", "Title3" based on column E cell value.

In other word, something like this :

```
if Cell E == 'index'
  add Cell A value to dropdown
end
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this? Can I do it using excel functions or do I need VBA? And if VBA is needed, any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you're writing _"based on column D cell value."_ and your pseudo-code actually uses some _Cell D_ but it compares it to `'index`` that your linked image shows in column "E" . Please clarify

Comment: I am sorry, I meant column E

Comment: then edit your question accordingly

Comment: Done! Thank you for letting me know!

Comment: you are welcome. did you try posted solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are dealing with a dropdown cell in excel UI, then you might use this code (see comments to adjust it to your actual needs):

```
Sub Main()
    With Worksheets("sheetWithDropDownName").Range("A1").Validation '<--| change "sheetWithDropDownName" and "A1" to your actual "dropdown" worksheet and cell references
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(GetTitles(), ",")
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub

Function GetTitles() As Variant
    Dim cell As Range, rng As Range

    With Worksheets("sheetWithDataName") '<--| change "sheetWithDataName" to your actual sheet with data name
        Set rng = .Range("A1", .cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))  '<--| set a range as its columns A:E range from row 1 down to last column E not empty row
    End With
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each cell In rng.Columns(5).cells
            If cell.Value = "index" Then .Item(cell.Offset(, -4).Value) = cell.Offset(, -4).Value
        Next cell
        GetTitles = .keys
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

With VBA, something like this might work. Combobox is supposed to be in a Form, data is supossed to be in a sheet named "MyData".

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer

lLastRow = Worksheets("MyData").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lLastRow
        If Worksheets("MyData").Cells(i, 5) = "index" Then
            ComboBox1.AddItem (Worksheets("MyData").Cells(i, 1))
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```